# Ruby: identify four-digit numbers and cut a text

Tags: ruby, date

so i'm dealing with a text (in string) containing many year numbers (four-digit), i'm trying to divide the text into segments each of which begins and ends with a year number (doesn't matter if the year number is included in the segment). basically year numbers just act like a signal for the code to 'cut'.

any ideas how i can do that? how to identify a four-digit num

thanks a million!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>> 'ab2010cd'.scan(/\D(\d{4})\D/)   # 4 digit numbers match
=> [["2010"]]
>> 'ab201cd'.scan(/\D(\d{4})\D/)    # <4 digit numbers don't match
=> []
>> 'ab20101cd'.scan(/\D(\d{4})\D/)  # >4 digit numbers don't match
=> []
>>
```

in ruby1.9 you can use lookahead/lookbehind assertions to do a split

```
>> 'ab2010cd'.split(/(?<=\D)(\d{4})(?=\D)/)
=> ["ab", "2010", "cd"]
```

Comment: thanks~ it works well
do u know how i can specify the search to four-digit that only in the forms of 19XX or 20XX?

Answer (score 1):

```
ruby-1.9.2-preview1 > "abc1234tgnh".match(/\d{4}/)
 => #<MatchData "1234">
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the string

```
s = 'abcd 1234 efghijk 56789 nope 0987 blah blah 2010 hmmm'
```

Should there be 2 or 3 matches (given the "2010 hmmm" substring does not end with a year)?  I'm going to assume you want to match that (if not, remove the `|\Z` from the regex).

```
s.scan(/\b\d{4}\b.+?(?=\b\d{4}\b|\Z)/)
# => ["1234 efghijk 56789 nope ", "0987 blah blah ", "2010 hmmm"]
```

But, as you say you don't care about keeping the numbers:

```
s.scan(/(?<=\d{4}).+?(?=\b\d{4}\b|\Z)/)
# => [" efghijk 56789 nope ", " blah blah ", " hmmm"]
```

Comment: thanks~ it works well do u know how i can specify the search to four-digit that only in the forms of 19XX or 20XX?

Comment: @es9999, simple enough.  just replace `\d{4}` with `(?:19|20)\d\d`